# Connect shared folder to power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, gateway

I have created a gateway with SQL connections. I wanted to connect an excel file that is stored on the company's shared folder but I keep getting an error:

[image]

I tried changing the file location to: "\\gvnas\GVNAS\N:\01. CORPORATE....\Compiled Dwell Time-Mail.xlsx" but it threw the same error.

[image]

I also have a power BI file with the same path and it works fine:
[image]

Comment: You should use file location  with the server name and without N:\  because this disc name is only for your PC 

"\\server\test\01. CORPORATE....\Compiled Dwell Time-Mail.xlsx"

Comment: I tried "\\gvnas\GVNAS\01. CORPORATE ....\Compiled Dwell Time - Mail.xlsx" and it throws the same error

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ? We are facing the exact same scenario here and we can't find a working solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you check to ensure all system, Power BI and SQL sever have access to the folder your trying to read from?

Comment: this should be a comment